# Unable to parse blank JSON String using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

> I am using gson to parse json data to model class but it throws errors as mentioned below.
>   I referred some of the SO questions but am unable to solve the problem. I am using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484353/gson-throws-malformedjsonexception) as reference.

**Customer.class**

```
public class Customer {

    private String Bank_Name;
    private String Bank_Bank;
    private String Bank_Account_Clabe;
    private String Bank_Accunt_Number;

    public String getBank_Name() {
        return Bank_Name;
    }

    public void setBank_Name(String bank_Name) {
        Bank_Name = bank_Name;
    }

    public String getBank_Bank() {
        return Bank_Bank;
    }

    public void setBank_Bank(String bank_Bank) {
        Bank_Bank = bank_Bank;
    }

    public String getBank_Account_Clabe() {
        return Bank_Account_Clabe;
    }

    public void setBank_Account_Clabe(String bank_Account_Clabe) {
        Bank_Account_Clabe = bank_Account_Clabe;
    }

    public String getBank_Accunt_Number() {
        return Bank_Accunt_Number;
    }

    public void setBank_Accunt_Number(String bank_Accunt_Number) {
        Bank_Accunt_Number = bank_Accunt_Number;
    }
}
```

**Json Response**

```
{
"Bank_Name": "",
"Bank_Bank": "",
"Bank_Account_Clabe": "",
"Bank_Accunt_Number": ""
}
```

**error Log**

```
System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 13 path $.Bank_Name
```

**code**

```
try {
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gb.create();

Customer customer = gson.fromJson(s, Customer.class);
setData(customer);

} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Customer` class?

Comment: @Henry check edit

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you sure you showed the exact JSON that gives the error?

Comment: yes  the same response i get.. i dont get it y gson throws error .. may be it doesnot support blank string

Comment: Though its for null values , but still can you please try serializeNulls() once in gson builder

Comment: You can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562157/gson-how-to-deserialize-array-or-empty-string

Comment: Actually i debugged the code what i found is 
{Bank_Name=, Bank_Bank=, Bank_Account_Clabe=, Bank_Accunt_Number=}.

Comment: @Henry how can i deal with such response

Comment: This is not JSON. Either fix the server to return proper JSON or write your own parser for this format.

Comment: May be the problem is in your server side code.Can you share it?

Comment: actually ... its fixed. thanks everyone